# How to remove telegram inline keyboard button after selected

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want remove InlineKyboardMarkup buttons after selected by user
My inline keyboard markup is:

```
InlineKeyboardMarkup keyLanguage = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(
                new InlineKeyboardButton[][]
                {
                    new InlineKeyboardButton[]
                    {
                        new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("English","Lan_EN"),
                        new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("Spain","Lan_SP")
                    }
                });
```

and also:

```
private void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs messageEventArgs)
    {
        var message = messageEventArgs.Message;

        if (message == null || message.Type != MessageType.TextMessage) return;

        if (message.Text.Contains("/start"))
        {

            t1.TBot_User_Insert(message.Chat.FirstName, message.Chat.Username, "A", message.Chat.Id);
            string Str = "Please Select Your Language.";
            Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, Str, replyMarkup: keyLanguage);
         } 
    } 
private void Bot_OnCallbackQuery(object sender, CallbackQueryEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CallbackQuery.Data.Contains("Lan_"))
        {
            t1.TBot_User_Update(e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, e.CallbackQuery.Data);
            string Str = t1.iMessage_Select("Welcome", e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id);

            Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, Str, replyMarkup: mainmenu);
        }
    }
```

How to remove KeyLanguage (inlinekeyboard) after selected?
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually `editMessageReplyMarkup`, and edit to an `[]` (empty) keyboards.